# How do I conform to UICollectionViewDelegate?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, protocols

I'm getting a compiler error of protocol non-comformance.  What am I missing?

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, section: Int) -> Int {
        //...
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {
        let cell: AnyObject = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("turkey", forIndexPath:indexPath)
        return cell as UICollectionViewCell
        //...
    }
}
```

```
swift:45:1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all `!` as the delegate is not using optionals according to the docs.

Comment: Oh, both method names are wrong. There's a part in the middle missing. Fix the names as per docs and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a cut/past of all the non-optional APIs and re-compiled.

  Apparently that works.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    // The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: AnyObject = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("turkey", forIndexPath:indexPath)
        return cell as UICollectionViewCell

    }
}
```